# Rotating Images in and out of an ImageView

Tags: java, android, image, animation, imageview

Is there a way I can rotate a bunch of images in an ImageView? I've tried to search this but the only results I get are regarding rotating an image (i.e. 90 degrees) in an ImageView. This isn't what I need. I want to be able to rotate a handful of images (basically like a GIF). Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at animating the `ImageView`?

Comment: I'm thinking there should be a way to set an animation to run through images with a specified interval, looking now...